# How to change DbSchema for Entity Framework at runtime?

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework

We are using EF5.0 in our project and we are supplying the Db Schema name using following code in the `OnModelCreating`event

```
string schemaName = DbSchema; 
modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new TableMap(schemaName));
```

But our problem is that the `OnModelCreating` event is called only once(even if I create context object again) and we need to change the Db Schema name for different databases which we are processing in a loop.

I believe that EF 6.0 has a method like `HasDefaultSchema` but I am unable to find a way for EF5.0

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest way is probably to use the `DbContext`'s ctor [overload that takes model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679391.aspx) [1]. That way you can create two different configurations (though different only in schema) and switch these as needed.

The model itself is represented by [`DbModel` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.infrastructure.dbmodel%28v=vs.113%29.aspx) and created by [`DbModelBuilder` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbmodelbuilder%28v=vs.113%29.aspx). It's almost the same as in `OnModelCreating` method. You can easily parametrize this.

[1] I suppose you want to use one context. If not, you I would go for different context classes.